# Good place to start kli yakar

Tags: commentaries, pentateuch-chumash

I've heard many great divrei torah from kli yakar, so I want to start learning kli yakar. I'm improving on my Hebrew skills, so I'd like to use a dictionary. What's a good parsha/perek of Chumash to start? By that I mean based on ease and intrigue.

---

As with all questions on this site, answers should be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, not merely opinions with no basis offered.

Comment: http://www.judaism.com/kli-yakar-shemos/dp/FDFAB/ kli yakar with english translation